# Search a QVariantList?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a list of SKUs (SKU - Stock Keeping Unit) in a `QVariantList`.

Is there a way to search the list and get data from the list?

For example, I want to search the list for "sku 0001" and get the associated title of the SKU.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like iterating through the list would be your only option, are you looking for another solution?

Comment: How can I iterate through it?

Comment: for(QVariantList::const_iterator it = list.begin();it!=list.end();++it){ if(it->toString()=="sku 0001") { ...} };

Comment: @Ilya Kobelevskiy: place as answer, OP could accept it.

Comment: What is a "sku" actually? A custom class?

Comment: @doc SKU stands for "Stock Keeping Unit", it's a common term in manufacturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(QVariantList::const_iterator it = list.begin();
    it!=list.end();
    ++it)
{ 
    if(it->toString()=="sku 0001") 
    { 
       your code...
    } 
};
```

Comment: Note that you need to use `list.constBegin()` and `list.constEnd()` to match `const_iterator` otherwise this code won't work. I tried to edit it but some asshat admin rejected it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Qt, but generally C++ provides overloaded `const` versions of both `begin` and `end`, which would apply if `list` is `const`.

Answer (score 5):

Use qFind from `<QtAlgorithms>`

e.g.:

```
QVariantList vl;
vl << 42 <<"hello"<<3.1415;
QVariantList::const_iterator v = qFind(vl,42);
int iv = (*v).toInt();
++v;
QString sv = (*v).toString();
```

Comment: this looks better then iterating, I didn't saw your answer when posting... However, in terms of performance, is qFind() more efficient then direct iteration or at the end it is the same thing?

Comment: I think, if one uses QVariantList (the only one use-case I can think about is accessing QML from C++ Qt), then the performance is not the issue. But the readability and clean code. Consider, you have large code with nested for-loops all iterating in Lists of similar type. So you could by mistake set iterator to begin of one container but check for the end of another. (Made this error several types using QDome nodes). Using qFind of foreach reduces the chance of such errors.

Comment: Note that if you want to check if the return of qFind() is valid use `if (v != v1.constEnd())`